# Preload images with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have search for quite awhile and can't quite find what will work to preload images that I am pulling from a jquery ajax call.

The .ajax call yields a response like "~1_~2_ etc".

```
$(".showPixFeature.hidden").live('click', function () { 
        var adID = this.id.split('_');
        $("#" + adID[0] + '_' + adID[1]).hide();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../classifieds/classAdPics.php",
        data: "ID="+ this.id,
        success: function(r){
            var images = r.split('~');
            var thumbs = '';
                var i=0;
                if(((images.length) - 1) > 1){
                for (i=1;i<=(images.length) - 1;i++)
                {
                thumbs = thumbs + '<img src="../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '_sm.jpg" id="' + adID[1] + '_' + images[i] + '" class="thumbNails">';
                }
                }
                thumbs = thumbs + '<div><img src="../images/listings/' + adID[1] + '_1_.jpg" id="' + adID[1] + '_Preview" class="thumbNails"></div>';
            $("#" + adID[0] + '_' + adID[1]).html(thumbs).slideDown();
            }
        });
   $(this).attr("src", "../images/close_pix.png");
   $(this).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');
    });
   $(".showPixFeature.shown").live('click', function () { 
         var adID = this.id.split('_');
        $("#" + adID[0] + '_' + adID[1]).slideUp();
        $(this).attr("src", "../images/class_see_more.png");
        $(this).removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');
   });
   $(".thumbNails").live('click', function() {
       var adID = this.id.split('_');
       $('#' + adID[0] + '_Preview').hide().attr('src', '../images/listings/' + this.id + '_.jpg').fadeIn('500');
   });
```

I would like to preload the images that are being called before the .slideup() call.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for images to [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) you can use .load to bind a handler to the image.  Something like this:

$('#myImage').load(function() {
  // this fires when the image is finished loading.
});